# How can I edit alignment and spacing in SwiftUI for images and text?

Tags: swiftui, position, alignment, spacing

I would like the Image **"Astronaut Meditation (Traced)**" and the text **"Levitate"** to be aligned as in the prototype image, which is in the dimensions of an iPhone 13 pro max. [How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYzxJ.png)
**Here is my ContentView code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack
        {
            //Background
            Image("Background")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top])
            
            
                **//Meditating Astronaut
                Image("Astronaut Meditaton  (Traced)")
                    
                    .position(x: 102, y: 106)
                //Levitate
                Text("Levitate")
                    .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .position(x: 110, y: 386)**
              
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I have included an image of how it is previewed on Xcode:
[How it looks in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSbly.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to achieve your actual desire design. Wrap your content in `VStack` and also add frame to `background` image for bind in your whole device with device width and height.

And also add `Spacer()` in `VStack` to occupy remains bottom space(For move view to up side).

```
ZStack {
        //Background
        Image("Background")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) //Here add frame to background image
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack { //Wrap your view in VStack
            //Meditating Astronaut
            Image("Astronaut Meditaton  (Traced)")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(.top,20)
            //Levitate
            Text("Levitate")
                .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            Spacer() //Add Spacer to move view to upper side.
            
        }.padding(.top,UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 + 150) //Add padding with safe area to top side for upper space(suitable for all devices).
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use static value alignment like **position** or **offset** because it’s not stable for all devices, instead just wrap your content inside **VStack{}** then you will achieve your desired design.

```
ZStack {
        //Background
        Image("Background")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top])
        
        VStack { //start wrapping after background color image
            //Meditating Astronaut
            Image("Astronaut Meditaton  (Traced)")
            //Levitate
            Text("Levitate")
                .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @tail said, you should avoid absolute `position` & `offset`, since it will vary from device to device. But if you do want to use them for some reason, you can add a `alignment` parameter to the `ZStack` and then use `offset` to get the desired outcome.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            //Background
            Image("Background")
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.top])

            //Meditating Astronaut
            Image(systemName: "gear")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .offset(y: -150)
            //Levitate
            Text("Levitate")
                .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(y: -50)
        }

    }
}
```

Even better way would be to use `GeometryReader` and work with relative values to the screen size:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                //Background
                Image("Background")
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.top])

                //Meditating Astronaut
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 5)

                //Levitate
                Text("Levitate")
                    .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                    // Position with offsetting by the size of image.
                    // Image frame 150 -> half is 75 + 25 for padding.
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 5 + 100)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

With `GeometryReader` I would use absolute position and calculate the position of image with the relative values and then use the image size in addition to position the text